# grouping records by a field and submit a query on each group in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I have a table like this:

```
create table product_company (
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    productName varchar(100),
    companyName varchar(100),
    price int
);
```

I want to know the name of the product which it has the second rank in price in each company.

for example if `company1` has three product `product1=30`, `product2=50` and `product3=15`(the assignment shows the price of each product in this company) so `product1` has the second rank in price property in `company1` and I want to write a query that returns something like below:

```
company1 product1
company2 ...
...
```

I mean for every company I want to know the product that has the second rank in price within that company.
I don't know how to use group by clause because group by is working fine by aggregate functions but I don't want the maximum in price.

**I want to write this query with standard sql queries and clauses and without some special funcions that may not work in some DBMS**

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: It doesn't matter. I can use (limit offset,index) but I don't know how to use something like this and write the correct query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use window function `dense_rank()`:

```
select *
from (
    select
        pc.*,
        dense_rank() over(partition by companyName order by price desc) rn
    from product_company pc
) t
where rn = 2
```

In earlier versions, one solution is to filter with a correlated subquery. But you have to be careful to properly handle possible top ties. This should do it:

```
select pc.*
from product_company pc
where (
    select count(distinct pc1.price) 
    from product_company pc1 
    where pc1.companyName = pc.companyName and pc1.price > pc.price
) = 1
```

Comment: Is this possible without using `dense_rank()`

Comment: just by standard sql clauses

Comment: mysql 5.7 is the version

Answer (score 2):

An EXISTS with a COUNT can also be used for this

**For example:**

> ```
> create table product_company (
>     id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
>     productName varchar(100),
>     companyName varchar(100),
>     price decimal(16,2)
> );
> ```

> ```
> insert into product_company 
> (productName, companyName, price) values
>  ('product 1', 'odd org', 9)
> ,('product 2', 'odd org', 15)
> ,('product 3', 'odd org', 11)
> ,('product 4', 'odd org', 17)
> ,('product 5', 'even inc.', 18)
> ,('product 6', 'even inc.', 12)
> ,('product 7', 'even inc.', 16)
> ,('product 8', 'even inc.', 14)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> select *
> from product_company t
> where exists
> (
>   select 1
>   from product_company t2
>   where t2.companyName = t.companyName
>     and t2.price >= t.price
>   having count(distinct t2.price) = 2
> )
> ```
>
> ```
> id | productName | companyName | price
> -: | :---------- | :---------- | ----:
>  2 | product 2   | odd org     | 15.00
>  7 | product 7   | even inc.   | 16.00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=fd5fd78ae7303dd9f6691409bdce5089)*

And if you want to have the top 2 per company?
Then change the `HAVING` clause

```
...
   having count(distinct t2.price) <= 2
...
```